# Struts 1.x Display Action Form property as simple text (label)

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I am confused. It should be very obvious, but I cannot figure it out :(

How can I display Action Form property as simple text (label) in my .jsp page?

I can use `<html:text>` tag, for example, to create an input text field for the desired property but how can I simply display this value as plain text using Struts 1.x?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<c:out value="${theActionForm.label}" />` using the JSTL or, if you really like Struts tags, `<bean:write name="theActionForm" property="label" />`.

This assumes that the action form is registered under the attribute name "theActionForm", and has a `getLabel()` method.

Comment: "This assumes that the action form is registered under the attribute name "theActionForm"". Does this mean the following entry in the struts-config.xml `<form-bean name="theActionForm" type="com.foo.ActionForm"/>`? then I completely missed the point that Action Form is also a bean visible in jsp... Thank you!

Comment: You got it. The name of the bean in the struts-config.xml is indeed the name of the request or session attribute under which Struts registeres the action form.